# SBT context error while using Fileservice.updatefile call

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt, fileupdate

I have been building a client to replace some content on the connections social website that we have. I have written a java client by following the sample code from the Github repo :https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/tree/master/sdk/com.ibm.sbt.core.test/src/test/java/com/ibm/sbt/services/client/connections/files

And also using a this tutorial as a reference to create endpoints and then passing it to different service.
http://bastide.org/2014/01/28/how-to-develop-a-simple-java-integration-with-the-ibm-social-business-toolkit-sdk/

To be clear , I am posting content on a community so I am using CommunityService to upload content and FileService to update community files.

This method works fine : fileservice.updateCommunityFile(iStream, fileId, title, communityLibraryId, params)
This creates multiple versions on the server which is not what I want.

However, I want to use this one - fileservice.updateFile(inputStream, file, params)
If I use the above one in my code it causes the below error :

```
Error updating the file
com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.files.FileServiceException: Error updating the file
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.files.FileService.updateFile(FileService.java:2686)
    at sbt.sample.standalone.java.StandaloneDemo.ReplacePhoto(StandaloneDemo.java:332)
    at sbt.sample.standalone.java.StandaloneDemo.main(StandaloneDemo.java:239)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SBT context is not initialized for the request
    at com.ibm.commons.runtime.Context.get(Context.java:57)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.BasicEndpoint.authenticate(BasicEndpoint.java:151)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.forceAuthentication(ClientService.java:296)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.processResponse(ClientService.java:1154)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService._xhr(ClientService.java:1072)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.execRequest(ClientService.java:1037)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.xhr(ClientService.java:1003)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.put(ClientService.java:937)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientService.put(ClientService.java:933)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.base.BaseService.updateData(BaseService.java:439)
    at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.files.FileService.updateFile(FileService.java:2683)
```

Note : The user that I am using in the program is the admin of the community to where content is posted.
Moreover is there any way I can specify in the sbtsdk api to replace the file other without creating other versions?

I found this to be similar - [Liferay Portal & IBM SBT SDK: SBT context is not initialized for the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958902/liferay-portal-ibm-sbt-sdk-sbt-context-is-not-initialized-for-the-request) 
But I don't understand if there was any resolution to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its hard to understand why you are seeing "SBT context is not initialized for the request" because you can run one fileservice API and not the other.

Both `fileservice.updateCommunityFile(iStream, fileId, title, communityLibraryId, params)` and  `fileservice.updateFile(inputStream, file, params)` create new versions. They do not replace the latest version. There is a parameter with this API which controls whether to create new version or not.

This is what you need to do:

use parameter createVersion with value "false". like this:

```
Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
paramsMap.put("createVersion", "false");
```

Now use this paramsMap in updateCommunityFile API like this:

```
fileservice.updateCommunityFile(iStream, fileId, title, communityLibraryId, paramsMap)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This solves my problem of not having multiple files on the community. However, I am not sure why I get context not initialized for some of the other fileservice methods. I have accepted your answer since it solves my problem for now.

Comment: How do you know about the "createVersion" parameter? Is it documented somewhere? I would like to find the documentation for this and other parameters that may be available. Thanks!

Comment: here is the documentation: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Updating_a_file_ic50&content=apicontent